# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpRequest.get_Query()

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-framework-version

[The project is an ASP.NET core project targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1.

On running the website, all pages work fine except that a few times it gives a NullReference exception on a few pages. Please let me know if someone has come across this issue and how has it been fixed? Thank you.
I have seen a few similar issues posted on GitHub but no concrete solution has been provided.

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpRequest.get_Query()
Stack Query Cookies Headers 
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpRequest.get_Query()      
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.QueryStringValueProviderFactory.CreateValue    
ProviderAsync(ValueProviderFactoryContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.CompositeValueProvider.CreateAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IList<IValueProviderFactory> factories)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.CompositeValueProvider.CreateAsync(ControllerContext controllerContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider+<>c__DisplayClass0_0+<<CreateBinderDelegate>g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

)][1]
```

[Links](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/3219)

Comment: Hi @Wilfred !! Were you able to fix this?